# Apache and Nginx both on port 80

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

I'm trying to install Nginx on my current cloud Cent OS server which has Apache httpd installed and running.

My hosting company tells me that Nginx and Apache can both run on port 80 at the same time so my plan was to transform .htaccess and Apache conf of Wordpress sites to Nginx after installing it via Yum.

I also Googled about this and some people suggest using Nginx as a reverse proxy and serve static files only but run Apache with PHP because Apache has PHP embedded and would consume less memory even though it doesn't support multiple concurrent requests like Nginx.

My gut feeling is that switching everything over to Nginx would be beneficial but unsure at this stage.

Also, is there anything I should watch out for when doing this switch over?

What would you do if it was you in this situation?

Comment: I used to run Apache, then switched to Nginx and there is a huge difference in speed with both php and static files. Nginx runs way faster.

Comment: There is no such thing as running 2 services listening on the same port. Running on port 80 on differend network interfaces is possible, but not on same interface (aka. every service must listen on a differend ip.)

Comment: _hosting company tells me that Nginx and Apache can both run on port 80 at the same time_... that's a new one, for me at least.

Comment: Time to get a new hosting company. It's possible if they're on different IP addresses (not just interfaces @Xnoise), but it is not possible to have two services listen on the same IP and same port (how would you know which traffic was meant for which?)

Comment: All sites are under unique IP addresses and they are all mapped separately with VirtualHost. Can I run both on port 80 then and remove Virtualhost for the site I want to transfer and configure this in Nginx config?

Comment: @JaeChoi: On which interfaces (IP Adresses) do you want to run the NGINX and the Apache server? Please write for both.

Comment: @hakre: They will be both on the same server and I'm puzzled whether I should use both Nginx for serving static files and Apache for proxy pass or just use Nginx. Wouldn't I get much more performance gain using just Nginx for the sites or is there not much of significant difference to it so I wouldn't worry about it and reduce the hassle of converting .htaccess files?

Comment: Same server: OK. *BUT:* On which IP adress(es)? Please provide a list of the both servers which IP adresses they should be listening on (and if not port 80 on which port, too).

Comment: Same port different computers...

Comment: They will be both on same virtual machine. VMware Cent OS environment. All the websites are just listening to different IP addresses in Apache httpd.conf file under Virtual Host setting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your hosting company means by their comment but you won't be able to run BOTH Apache and Nginx on port 80. Once one is bound to port 80 the other will be unable to bind to it.

Probably the best configuration in your current situation would be to put Nginx on port 80 and Apache on 8000 or similar.

Use nginx to serve static files (see try_files because ["if" is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)) and then proxy all requests for PHP to port 8000 using the [HTTP proxy module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule).

The other common configuration for PHP with Nginx is to use PHP-FPM and proxy via FastCGI, just google "PHP-FPM Nginx {Your OS} tutorial" for a tutorial.

There [much debate](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php-fpm%20vs%20mod_php) about the performance of PHP-FPM/mod_php but in my personal experience I have found PHP-FPM more performant.

Comment: I agree, PHP-FPM is way faster on my server than mod_php was.

Comment: @Thom Seddon: Thanks for this. Is there other implications for changing over for either method on caching such as APC? Would it not have any effect as it's a PHP package?

Comment: You're quite right, as it's a PHP extension it wouldn't make a difference. The only difference I can think of are that mod_php does expose a few extra PHP functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apache.php) but you can definitely work without them (PHP 5.4 actually brings a few of them into core so they are always available, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

Comment: Unless each service is attached to a different IP. Then it is possible to use port 80 for both Apache and Nginx.

Answer (score 11):

I would use nginx as the web facing server on port 80 and proxy pass to apache which would be running on a different port. Many sites run this configuration. Serving static files with nginx is much more efficient than with apache. It is actually a lot simpler than it may sound.

[This document](http://blog.ludovf.net/configure-nginx-to-proxy-virtual-hosts-to-apache/) explains in detail.

Comment: TRENT your link is currently broken. Do you know where the content has moved to? Would it be possible for you to summarize that content in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your externally facing webserver to the public IP address and the internally facing webserver to localhost (127.0.0.1:80).

So if you are using Nginx publicly then bind that to the public IP address and have it proxy to Apache at localhost.

Its better to use separate ports to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Can you explain precisely how to do this?